# Python issue - URL reference error but no apparent problem

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I'm in the process of learning Python using Miguel's MegaTutorial as a basis for my system (I'm very much a novice). Having got it working reasonably well I went away for two days, returned, turned on my computer and am now getting errors when I run the system event though it appears to be working properly.

Every single screen request works as I would expect but in Pycharm's log the error messages below are output which suggest the URL is incorrect. I did make some changes when I started up the system but I then backed them all out (as far as I'm aware) using the PYcharm VCS Local History facility.

I haven't posted the code at this time as I'm hoping I'm doing something obvious and stupid, also, I don't know what code would be causing the problem as all the references are to downloaded software I haven't touched.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2019 22:35:11] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1925, in dispatch_request
    self.raise_routing_exception(req)
  File "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1907, in raise_routing_exception
    raise request.routing_exception
  File "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\ctx.py", line 350, in match_request
    result = self.url_adapter.match(return_rule=True)
  File "C:\Users\tribl\PycharmProjects\CM2020\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 1799, in match
    raise NotFound()
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a problem with your code (aside from failing to catch an exception). Rather, the remote resource simply isn't available anymore.

Comment: Update: I've cleared browsing data, reset my browser (Chrome) and tried it with Edge and the problem has stopped. It is now working with Chrome too.   Still no idea of the root cause but pleased I can move on

Comment: It seems unusual that the werkzerug 404 (not found) is being turned into a 500 (internal error). Is it possible that something is amiss in your error handling? Since you're following the Mega Tutorial, this'd be near your `@bp.app_errorhandler(404)`. Could you show us that code?

Comment: Thanks Dave, problem went when i changed to Edge. The error handler code is below. I have other issues with that yet to resolve, primarily with username not always being available       from flask import render_template
from app import db
from app.errors import bp
from app.models import User, Club


@bp.app_errorhandler(404)
def not_found_error(error):
 #   user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()
    club = Club.query.filter_by(clubnum=user.club).first_or_404()
    clubname = club.clubname
    logo = club.logo
    return render_template('errors/404.html'), 404

Answer (score 2):

Using a different browser (Edge) and stopping and starting the existing one (Chrome) resolved this issue although I still don't understand the root cause